# How to use limit and sort query in wso2esb dataservice experssion

Tags: mongodb, wso2-esb

I try to query documents and get last value from that result by using following query.

```
dbname.find({"name":"test"}).limit(1).sort({$natural:-1})
```

But in result I got all the documents which contains name as test.

Kindly let me know where I made mistake

Answer (score 0):

> Try please code

```
 dbname.find({}).limit(1).sort({$natural:-1})
```

> You can use below code also

```
dbname.findOne({name:'test'}).sort({$natural:-1})
```